# How to set SVG file to image view in Android Xamarin?

Tags: svg, xamarin.android

I am using the below code to set the svg file as image view source.

imageView.SetImageDrawable(Resources.System.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Typogy1));
it throws an exception. Please suggest me how to set the svg file to image view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [example](https://medium.com/@_jamesmundy/using-svgs-in-xamarin-android-18d46d2f027d) by James Mundy is really good for SVG usage in xamarin android.

But recently in a chat with him, he said and as well as, in my opinion, the best way of using SVG's in an Android application is using [Vector Drawables](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Drawables.VectorDrawable/). (Much better than using any libraries)

Vector drawable's are easy to use, maintain and are very lightweight in comparison to images which makes them even better.

An [example](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportvectordrawable?version=23.2.1) of how to use it.

Creating SVG vector drawable's is very easy too, using [this](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)

**Update:**

**Vector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="96dp"
android:width="96dp"
android:viewportHeight="48"
android:viewportWidth="48" >
<group>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#393939"
        android:pathData="M12 36l17-12-17-12v24zm20-24v24h4V12h-4z" />
</group>
</vector>
```

Place this XML in a folder inside your Resources for eg your drawable folder or your layout folder, then use it as follows :

```
_yourImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Vector);
```

Goodluck!

Revert in case of any queries.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you tell me how set the image view source using SetImageDrawable in android xamarin. Created the svg files but i can't set the source as svg.

Comment: Do you want to set the image source programmatically?

Comment: Yes, i tried this way "  SetImageDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.vector));" but Resources.GetDrawable(int) is deprecated. so it is not working. I tried another way "Resources.GetDrawable("Typogy1.svg");" it return always null value. How to get the svg file from the drawable?

Comment: Is there any way to set the svg file in the image resource? Like the below code.        sample.svg:                                                                             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g transform="translate(6.856 1)">
      <path fill="#413E08" d="M14.5353052 3.27989968C14.7182756 3.93468771 /> like that.

Comment: I don't understand your question properly can you be a bit clear about what you want

Comment: I am having the sample.svg file. How to refer to the image view?. This is my question. i tried this "_yourImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Vector);" it return null value. Now i convert the svg file to XML. It is working now.

Comment: See you need to put your svg image into the link i have referred above, then with the xml you get create a xml file and then use that xml file as your background for the image